# TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [(2,)] of <class 'tuple'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, slice, argument-unpacking

I've a user defined function as follows:-

```
def genre(option,option_type,*limit):
    option_based = rank_data.loc[rank_data[option] == option_type]
    top_option_based  = option_based[:limit]
    print(top_option_based)
    top_option_based.to_csv('top_option_based.csv')
    return(top_option_based))
```

please refer this[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v85CP.png)

when I use the function as

```
genre('genre','Crime',2)
```

I'm getting an error as

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [(2,)] of <class 'tuple'>".
```

Comment: it seems you need remove `*` - `genre(option,option_type,limit)`

Comment: You also have an additional closing bracket in the return line, probably a typo.  I would add that as the function stands no one can run or define it as there are missing items to make it function, such as rank_data does not exist.  try and make the question complete otherwise solving can be difficult if there are too many unknowns in the snippet to begin with.

Comment: but when I'm importing this function in another file I'm getting an error as ''genre() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given''. In order to avoid this error I used *

Comment: I've inserted the image of my rank_data in ''image''

Answer (score 1):

I think you need remove `*` from `*limit` if argument `limit` is `integer` and `rank_data`:

```
def genre(option,option_type,limit):
    option_based = rank_data.loc[rank_data[option] == option_type]
    top_option_based  = option_based[:limit]
    print(top_option_based)
    top_option_based.to_csv('top_option_based.csv')
    return(top_option_based)
```

With borrowing sample with another answer it works perfectly:

```
def genre(option,option_type,limit):
    option_based = rank_data.loc[rank_data[option] == option_type]
    top_option_based  = option_based[:limit]
    print(top_option_based)
    top_option_based.to_csv('top_option_based.csv')
    return(top_option_based)

print (genre('genre', 'Crime', 2))
   genre
0  Crime
1  Crime
```

EDIT:

I think you need add `dataframe` as argument too:

```
def genre(rank_data, option,option_type,limit):
    option_based = rank_data.loc[rank_data[option] == option_type]
    top_option_based  = option_based[:limit]
    print(top_option_based)
    top_option_based.to_csv('top_option_based.csv')
    return(top_option_based)

print (genre(rank_data, 'genre', 'Crime', 2))
   genre
0  Crime
1  Crime
```

Comment: ok but when I'm importing this function in another file I'm getting an error as ''genre() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given''. In order to avoid this error I used *

Comment: Then check another answer.

Comment: It seems you need add argument - dataframe.

Comment: Tried it, but not getting.

Comment: yes. TypeError: genre() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given. the problem occurs when i use the function in new file.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe `rank_data`

```
rank_data = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        genre=['Crime'] * 4 + ['Romance'] * 4
    ))

print(rank_data)

     genre
0    Crime
1    Crime
2    Crime
3    Crime
4  Romance
5  Romance
6  Romance
7  Romance
```

I'm going to assume you wanted to get the 2nd element of the slice due to your passing a `2` to your function.  In that case, I'm going to assume you want to use `iloc` and skip the preceding `:`.

Also, the unpacking of the `*limit` returns a tuple, we'll want a list.

```
def genre(option,option_type,*limit):
    option_based = rank_data.loc[rank_data[option] == option_type]
    top_option_based  = option_based.iloc[list(limit)]
               # I changed this bit  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    top_option_based.to_csv('top_option_based.csv')
    return(top_option_based)
```

---

```
genre('genre', 'Crime', 2)

   genre
2  Crime
```

---

```
genre('genre', 'Crime', 2, 3)

   genre
2  Crime
3  Crime
```

Comment: I don't need the second element. I need element upto 2(limit)